# Passing 'out' variables to function

Tags: fish

I'm trying to make my `fish_prompt` fancier by having the colors of my username and host change depending on what they are. However, if this attempt fails, I'd rather leave the colors as defaults of `$fish_color_[host|user]` So far, this works:

```
function fish_prompt
    # …
    set -l color_host $fish_color_host
    if command -qs shasum
        set color_host (colorize (prompt_hostname))
    end
    # …
    echo -n -s \
        (set_color --bold $color_user)      "$USER" \
        (set_color normal)                  @ \
        (set_color $color_host)             (prompt_hostname) \
        ' ' \
        (set_color --bold $color_cwd)       (prompt_pwd) \
        (set_color normal)                  " $suffix "
end

function colorize
    echo -n (printf "$argv" | shasum -ta 256 - | cut -c 59-64 | tr -d '\n')
end
```

At this point, I thought that this would look a lot cleaner if the `shasum` check were in `colorize` instead of being repeated in `fish_prompt`. I then tried this, figuring I might be able to pass the variable name if I single quoted it:

```
function fish_prompt
    # …
    set -l color_user $fish_color_user
    colorize_more 'color_user' "$USER"
    # …
end

function colorize_more -a what -a whence
    if command -qs shasum
        set "$what" (printf "$whence" | shasum -ta 256 - | cut -c 59-64 | tr -d '\n')
    end
end
```

However, this doesn't appear to change `$color_user` in `fish_prompt`. I suspect that's because the `set` in `colorize_more` can't modify a variable that's local to the one in `fish_prompt`, as the color that *should* come out of colorize_more is a yellow instead of the green that I get from `$fish_color_user`.

How can I restructure my `fish_prompt` and accessory function(s) so that I have a `colorize` function that sets a variable to some value only if it is able to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities here.

One is the "--no-scope-shadowing" flag to `function`

```
function colorize_more -a what -a whence --no-scope-shadowing
```

that will keep the outer local scope visible. This won't work with e.g. $argv, and if you need any variables they could potentially overwrite externally defined ones, so this is to be used with care.

Another is to define the variables as global instead - this has the disadvantage that they'll then stay defined and will conflict with any global variable of the same name.

Another is to output the value instead of assigning it.

E.g.

```
function colorize_more -a whence
    if command -qs shasum
        echo (printf "$whence" | shasum -ta 256 - | cut -c 59-64 | tr -d '\n')
    end
end

set -l color_user (colorize_more $USER)
set -q color_user[1]; or set color_user $fish_color_user
# or you could let colorize_more output $fish_color_user if it wouldn't output anything else
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by faho's comment of "Another is to output the value instead of assigning it", I ended up doing this:

```
function fish_prompt --description 'Write out the prompt'
    # …

    set -l color_host (colorize (prompt_hostname) "$fish_color_host")
    set -l color_user (colorize "$USER"           "$fish_color_user")

    # …
end


function colorize -a what -a default -d 'Outputs a hex color for a string or, failing that, a default'
    if command -qs shasum
        echo -n (printf "$what" | shasum -ta 256 - | cut -c 59-64 | tr -d '\n')
    else
        echo "$default"
    end
end
```